# Print Server Migration and Client Installs

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-printer, print-server, shared-printers

I am migrating to a new print server running Windows 2008R2. The hardware will be new, but I will use the old print server's IP, host name, printers and settings.

Will my clients using these printers need re-installation? Or can I just swap the servers and everything will run normally?  I want be sure the shared TCP/IP printers do not rely on the hardware spec or MAC of the print server.

Comment: Provided you keep "everything" the same on the server side, you won't need to re-install anything at the client.

Comment: Thank you  jscott   for helping newbie here  ^ ^

even google dont seem to get clear question 
i know it stupid question but i dont know where to ask i dont Have Enough HW to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be fine with your plan to just swap in the new print server. If you retain the old IP, hostname, ports, printers and queues your clients should not even notice the change.

Microsoft provides a tool [`printbrm.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj134237.aspx) which can help with print server migrations.  They also provide a guide [Mirgate Print Servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722360.aspx) with additional information.